# SQL Server - COUNT function - possible conflict with GROUP BY?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using the below code in a view in order to extract some data from a table:

```
SELECT

esli.fDocumentGID AS DocGID,
count(esli.LineNumber) X,
esli.GID AS LineGID,
esli.LineNumber AS ItemNum,
esit.BarCode AS EAN,
esic.Code AS BuyerItemID,
esit.Code AS SellerItemID,
'' AS CustomTariffNumber,
'CU' AS ProductIdentifierExt,
ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esli.Quantity), '0')*CONVERT(int, ISNULL(esim.Relation, 0)) AS PacketContentQuantity,
ISNULL(esim.fMUCode, '') AS PackageType,
ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esli.Quantity), '0') AS QuantityValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS QuantityValueWithdrawn,
-------------------------------------------

'S' AS TaxCategoryCoded,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxCategoryCodesWas,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(esvc.Description, 'TVA', ''), '%', ''), '')) AS TaxPercent,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxPercentWas,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esdt.CurrencyVATValue) AS TaxAmount,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxAmountWithdrawn,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esdt.CurrencyPayableAmount) AS MonetaryGrossValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS MonetaryGrossValueWithdrawn,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esdt.CurrencyNetValue) AS MonetaryNetValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS MonetaryNetValueWithdrawn,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), (esli.Quantity*esli.Price-esli.GrossDiscountValue)) AS MonetaryAmountPayable,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS MonetaryAmountPayableWithdrawn,
-------------------------------------------


esimit.fMUCode AS UnitOfMeasure,
esim.fMUCode AS UnitOfMeasureXCBL,
esimit.fMUCode AS PackUnitOfMeasure,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), esli.NetValue) AS UnitPriceValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS UnitPriceValueWas,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), esli.TotalValue) AS UnitPriceValueGross,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS UnitPriceValueGrossWas,
-------------------------------------------

LEFT(esit.Description, 35) AS ItemName,
'123' AS BuyerOrderNumberDet,
'1900-01-01' AS BuyerOrderDateDet,

-- Delivery detail --
ISNULL(esdtt.ADCode, '0') AS DeliveryDocumentNumberDet,
CONVERT(nvarchar(50), ISNULL(esdtt.ADRegistrationDate, '1900-01-01'), 101) AS DeliveryDateDet,
COUNT(esli.LineNumber) AS NumberOfLines,
CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esli.CurrencyNetValue) AS NetValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS NetValueDiff,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esli.TaxesValue) AS TaxValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxValueDiff,
-------------------------------------------

'' AS TaxableValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxableValueDiff,
-------------------------------------------

CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esdt.CurrencyPayableAmount) AS GrossValue,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS GrossValueDiff,
-------------------------------------------

-- Tax --
'S' AS TaxCategoryCodedd,
CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(esvc.Description, 'TVA', ''), '%', ''), '')) AS TaxPercent2,
CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), esdt.CurrencyVATValue) AS TaxNettoAmount,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxNettoAmountDiff,
-------------------------------------------

'' AS TaxableAmountt,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxableAmounttDiff,
-------------------------------------------

'' AS TaxAmountt,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxAmountDiff,
-------------------------------------------

'' AS TaxGrossAmount,

-- Se aplica doar pentru storno/corectie --
'' AS TaxGrossAmountDiff
-------------------------------------------




FROM ESFILineItem esli
JOIN ESFIDocumentTrade esdt ON esli.fDocumentGID=esdt.GID
LEFT JOIN ESFIDocumentTrade esdtt ON esdt.ADReferenceCode=esdtt.ADCode
JOIN ESFIItem esit ON esli.fItemGID=esit.GID
JOIN ESMMItemCodes esic ON esit.GID=esic.ItemGID
JOIN ESMMItemMU esim ON esli.fItemMUGID=esim.GID
JOIN ESGOZVATCategory esvc ON esli.fVATCategoryCode=esvc.Code
JOIN ESMMItemmu esimit ON esit.fMainMUGID=esimit.GID


WHERE esli.fDocumentGID=(SELECT TOP 1 GID FROM ERPBasic.dbo.EDINet_Invoices_Auchan)


GROUP BY  esli.LineNumber, esit.BarCode, esic.Code, esit.Code, esli.Quantity, esim.Relation, esim.fMUCode, esvc.Description,  esdt.CurrencyVATValue,
esdt.CurrencyPayableAmount, esdt.CurrencyNetValue, esli.Price, esli.GrossDiscountValue, esimit.fMUCode, esli.NetValue, esli.TotalValue, esit.Description, esli.CurrencyNetValue,
esli.TaxesValue, esli.fDocumentGID, esli.GID, esdtt.ADCode, esdtt.ADRegistrationDate


GO
```

The point is that, even though I have used `COUNT` function to count how many lines are in the document lines, I always get 1 on both rows. Shouldn't be the result 2? Is there anything that I am missing or I haven't used in a proper way?

I'm thinking that it might be something related to `GROUP BY` clause which I haven't used it properly.

**OUTPUT**

```
DocGID                                  X   LineGID
5236BD3F-668E-4B1E-9B3D-34E77B895FF1    1   2721B7D7-7AB6-44EC-BADB-F5F936DEDFE9
5236BD3F-668E-4B1E-9B3D-34E77B895FF1    1   70D9D3AE-5691-42C5-8212-EE7E079FC17F
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using esli.GID in Group By clause which is different for the rows..

Comment: I thought it might be from here. The point is that I need to use it because I'm using it further in a stored procedure...

Comment: If you are using that in group by, you will get the result like that only.